# Vector space is decomposed into direct sum of its subspace and its orthogonal complement

Tags: vector-spaces, bilinear-form

Let $E$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over the field $k$ and let $g$ be a bilinear form which is symmetric, antisymmetric or hermitian. Let $V$ be a subspace of $E$. Let $V_1 = \{ x| x \in E, g(x,a)=0\ \forall a \in V\}$. Prove that $E$ is a direct sum of $V$ and $V_1$. This result is used in the proof as well-known but unfortunately I can't find the proof of it. The proof I know is in the case of $g$ being inner product.

Comment: Well, if you can't "find the proof" come up with your own! Or at least try...

Comment: This is false as stated, you need some kind of non-deneracy hypothesis on $g$.  For example, if $g(x,y) = 0$ for all $x$ and $y$, then $g$ is symmetric.  Now, let $V = E$.  Then $V_1 = E$, but $E\not\cong E\oplus E$ (for finite dimensional vector spaces).

Comment: It's also false for antisymmetric forms---over $k^2$ (except perhaps in characteristic $2$), for any $1$-dimensional subspace $V \subset k^2$ we have $V_1 = V$, so $V + V_1$ is not a direct sum.

Answer (score 2):

Hint in the finite dimensional case. Let $\;n=\dim_kE=n\;$ and take a basis of $\;V_1\;,\;\{v_1,..,v_k\}$ . Complete this to a basis of the whole space: $\;\{v_1,..,v_k,v_{k+1},...,v_n\}\;$ . Using Gram-Schmidt we can assume this is an orthonormal basis, and  then

$$\{v_{k+1},...,v_n\}\;\;\text{is a basis of}\;\;V$$

In fact, I can't see how this is *really* different from the usual proof for inner products
...

Comment: Don't we need to follow a Gram-Schmidt-like process to have $\{v_{k+1},\ldots,v_n\}\subset V$?

Comment: No...why would we?

Comment: Well, if $V\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ is $Span\{(1,0)\}$, and we take the standard inner product, then $\{(0,1)\}$ is a basis for $V_1$. One could complete it to a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$ in the following way: $\{(0,1),(1,1)\}$, but naturally $(1,1)\not\in V$.

Comment: I think you have a point there, @JonathanY. I shall edit later, perhaps...or delete as it is late now. Thanks.